# Do Lucio's effects have a limited range?

Tags: overwatch

Lucio is a fun character, providing AoE healing or speed boost to teammates. But how is this area determined? I know that it's at least partially based on line of sight, but does it also have a limited range? Similarly, is his sonic barrier applied to all living allies, all allies in line of sight, or all allies within a certain range?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this [guide](http://segmentnext.com/2016/05/24/overwatch-lucio-guide-counters-ability-tips-strategy-strengths-weaknesses/),

> Do note that his healing ability will not have any effect on targets out of his line of sight and outside of a <s>30-meter</s> [10 meter](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/L%C3%BAcio#Crossfade) radius

Also after playing Lücio extensively, I can confirm that this in fact holds true. If someone is very far away down a straightaway, I haven't been able to heal them, but as soon as I get closer, they start being healed. Also the drop off once LOS is lost is pretty quick, but I cannot say if it is instant. The pickup for the healing is instant once they enter LOS however.

Note: the 10 meter radius extends radially in all directions, so even if you are higher or lower than him, you will still be healed if you are within 10 meters and in LOS.

Answer (score 5):

[As of the Overwatch Uprising update released April 11th, 2017](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/game/patch-notes/pc/#patch-35780), Lúcio's aura effects have been reworked. It included the following changes to Lucio's Crossfade aura effects.

> - Crossfade
>
>   - **Area of effect radius has been decreased from 30 meters to 10 meters**
>   - Heal Song
>
>     - Healing-per-second has been increased by 30% (also applies to Lúcio's Amp It Up ability)
>     - Self-healing has been reduced by 25%

In addition to decreasing his range, an in-game visual has been added to illustrate the effect radius. It is only visible to Lúcio and his teammates.

[image: In-game representation Lúcio's effect range]