# How does Lucio's aura work vertically?

Tags: overwatch

If I play Lucio, can I heal the teammates located at a different height? (roof, upstairs, hovering Pharah... )

In other word is that aura strictly horizontal? Or does it work more like a bubble like Winston's barrier?

If it's horizontal, does it require Line Of Sight or not? (will I heal a nearby ally right behind a wall?)

Comment: Although this specific detail isn't addressed in the current answer, I still think that the question is a duplicate of https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/267028/108003

Comment: The other answer has been updated and now addresses this specific detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lúcio's aura's area of effect is a sphere that surround him. So, yes, if you are flying away with Pharah/Mercy but you are still within the aura's displayed area, you will be healed **ONLY** if you are also in that sphere. If you are flying in that sphere, Lúcio will heal you. Also, Lúcio needs to have line of sight to heal you, however, you don't need line of sight for the speed song.

Keep in mind while using Lúcio, if you lose line of sight with a teammate, that player will be healed for a limited time before losing the effect (like with Zenyatta's orbs).

Comment: This is not fully correct - LoS is needed for both abilities in the 10m radius that he provides. http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/L%C3%BAcio#Abilities

Comment: Its true that on the wiki said you need to have LoS for both auras but on my experience I got speed without LoS on lucio and viceversa. I don't know if it is a bug or its just patched.

Comment: I've never been able to get a speed boost being on the opposite side of a wall while still in his range - same goes for healing.

Comment: That happen to me only with speed, never with healing. Maybe because i was without LoS with speed and run the extra limit and then having LoS again.

Comment: Regardless, I wouldn't say 'you don't need line of sight to the speed song' - you're experience of what you *think* is happening isn't backed.

Comment: Sometimes it seems like it goes through walls, since it lasts a moment even after losing LoS.